# BigQuery information schema - how to query (invalid project id and other errors)?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've set up a sample project called "el-in-dev-poc" and created some datasets in `europe-west3` region.

The Service Account I use to connect has the permissions needed to query `information_schema` as outlined here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables

[image]

Here are the queries that I tried and all failed:

#### Region only

```sql
SELECT * FROM `region-europe-west3`.information_schema.tables
```

```
Access Denied: Table region-europe-west3:information_schema.tables: User does not have permission to query table region-europe-west3:information_schema.tables, or perhaps it does not exist in location US.
```

Here I don't understand why it's still saying anything about US?

#### Project name only

```sql
SELECT * FROM el-in-dev-poc.information_schema.tables
```

```
Not found: Dataset el-in-dev-poc:information_schema was not found in location US
```

#### Region and project, both qith backticks

```sql
SELECT * FROM `el-in-dev-poc`.`region-europe-west3`.information_schema.tables
```

```
Invalid project ID 'el-in-dev-poc.region-europe-west3'. Project IDs must contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes. Some project IDs also include domain name separated by a colon. IDs must start with a letter and may not end with a dash.
```

I'm at a loss here and can't find any answers as to what is wrong here.

Comment: try FROM `el-in-dev-poc`.`region-europe-west3`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES (caps letters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the part `information_schema.tables` is case-sensitive.

please try

```
SELECT * FROM `el-in-dev-poc`.`region-europe-west3`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

example screenshots: in all small, doesn't work

[image]

In all caps - this works

[image]

Comment: Geez, I must have missed this information in the docs, or it wasn't given.. thanks a lot!